# dc.js barchart x-axis using an aggregated dimension

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, dimension

In the [NASDAQ 100 example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), is it possible to plot months by fluctuation?  That is, calculate a fluctuation rate by month and use it as the dimension or X-axis in the bar chart?

Comment: I'm sure it can be done but I'm not sure what you mean. Fluctuation by day is calculated with [`(d.close - d.open) / d.open * 100`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html). How would you calculate the fluctuation over an entire month? Close on last day of month minus open on first day of month?

Comment: Yes.  Or more generally...for the bubble chart, one is able to use a calculated and aggregated metric (Index Gain by Year) and use it as the X-axis.  Can the same be done for the bar chart?